# C - Thread stuck indefinitely while waiting

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, thread-synchronization

I'm having trouble with implementing the "dining philosopher" problem. Basically my program is stuck in an infinite loop while threads are waiting. I'am trying to implement it in a way so that it enforces the **order of eating**. so Philosopher 0 would eat first and then philosopher 1 and so on. The problem arises only when I try to enforce order of eating but not when I let the eating order be random.

Here is my implementation with order of eating emphasis (the one stuck in the infinite loop):

```
void *philosopherThread(void *threadIndex){
    int philID = (int)threadIndex;
    int nextIndex = 0;
    printf("This is philosopher %d\n", philID);

    // waiting status
    thinking(philID);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    // when the ith philosopher thread completes "thinking," the thread should check whether it is the ith philosopher's turn to eat or not prior to obtaining the chopsticks
    // If nextIndex==philID, the ith philosopher will grab both chopsticks and begin eating
    if(philID ==nextIndex){
        pickUpChopsticks(philID);
        eating(philID);
        putDownChopsticks(philID);
    }
    // waits on conditional variable
    while(nextIndex != philID){
        pthread_cond_wait(&var, &lock);
    }

    pickUpChopsticks(philID);
    eating(philID);
    putDownChopsticks(philID);

    // after finished eating it will  increment the value of nextIndex and release the lock to wake up all threads that are waiting on the conditional variable
    nextIndex++;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&var);
    return(NULL);
}
```

For reference, here is my implementation where **order of eating isn't emphasize** (this one works, no infinite loop)

```
void *philosopherThread(void *threadIndex){
    int philID = (int)threadIndex;
    printf("This is philosopher %d\n", philID);

    // waiting status
    thinking();

    // acquire locks
    pickUpChopsticks(philID);
    eating();

    // release lock
    putDownChopsticks(philID);

    return(NULL);
}
```

So I need help with the first code so that it isn't stuck in an infinite loop any longer. Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: The "distance" between mutex_lock and cond_wait is concerning. What's what in the middle???  Also, you exit the thread with the mutex locked.

Comment: The bottom one can deadlock. It most definitely doesn't "work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems:

- Each thread has its own `nextIndex`. There should only be one.
- The thread is still holding a lock on the mutex when it exits.
- The "distance" between mutex_lock and cond_wait is concerning. What's what in the middle???  You're waiting for your turn to eat, so there shouldn't be anything else performed.

```c
static int nextIndex = 0;

void *philosopherThread(void *threadIndex){
    int philID = (intptr_t)threadIndex;           // Use intptr_t on the outside too.
    printf("This is philosopher %d\n", philID);

    // We're thinking.
    thinking(philID);

    // Wait for our turn.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(nextIndex != philID)
        pthread_cond_wait(&var, &lock);

    // We're eating.
    pickUpChopsticks(philID);
    eating(philID);
    putDownChopsticks(philID);

    // We're back to thinking.
    thinking(philID);

    // Make it someone else's turn, and have all of the
    // waiting philosophers check if its their turn to eat.
    nextIndex++;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&var);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}
```